# Capybara sends unexpected google http requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

In my Rails 7 app I've got a simple single page web form where user has an input text field and submit button. After user provide some text inside of the field and push the submit button, the form submission is handled asynchronously via Turbo. I prepared a feature test with Capybara:

```
  context 'when the user enters a valid params', js: true do
    it 'renders the image after async form submision' do
      breed = Faker::Creature::Dog.breed

      visit root_path
      fill_in 'breed', with: breed

      click_button 'Submit'

      expect(page).to have_css("turbo-frame[id='dog-image']")
    end
   end
```

When I run this test I'm getting a weird HTTP requests:

```
     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/latest-patch-versions-per-build.json with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Host'=>'googlechromelabs.github.io', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}
```

I allowed localhost request, as per my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rails_helper'
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  
  WebMock.disable_net_connect! allow_localhost: true
  Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true }
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
  Capybara.server_host = 'localhost'
  Capybara.server_port = 3000
  Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost'
end
```

I think it's a configuration issue since when I put `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` the test will be green. I don't think it's a good practice to put `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` there. What did I missed in my setup?

Comment: I think its simply chrome looking for updates. Instead of using WebMock.allow_net_connect! just selectively whitelist that URI. https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#external-requests-can-be-disabled-while-allowing-specific-requests